# celery start worker automatically on boot with secure redis

Tags: redis, django-celery, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to start celery worker and celery beat on startup. celery worker to start with.

using ubuntu 20.04, redis, celery, python 3.8.10,  django 4.0.7, virtual env

1. Followed the link to install redis and secure with password (using requirepass foobared) and disabled dangerous commands
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04
2. now to automate the celery worker start on boot following the link
   [Celery: Start Worker Automatically (on boot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619845/celery-start-worker-automatically-on-boot)
   ("worker" is the sudo user, Virutal env is at "/home/worker/Fusion/envFCorp")

my /etc/default/celeryd looks like this

```
#Where your Celery is present
CELERY_BIN="/home/worker/Fusion/envFCorp/bin/celery"

# App instance to use 
CELERY_APP="app.celery"
#CELERY_APP="FusionCorp"

# Where to chdir at start
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/worker/Fusion/FusionCorp/FusionCorp/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker 
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename. 
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log" 
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"


# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
# You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
# A user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody). 
CELERYD_USER="celery" 
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured. 
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
export SECRET_KEY="MYSECRETPASSWORD"
```

2. redis-cli ping and pong is working good
3. (envFCorp) worker@server:~/Fusion$ sudo systemctl enable redis

   Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on alias name or linked unit file: redis.service
4. I am able to run celery worker and also able to schedule with beat manually if requirepass is off else it start giving error

   celery -A FusionCorp worker --loglevel=info --pool=gevent --concurrency=10

celery -A FusionCorp.celery beat

Now after activating the Virtual Environment

```
(envFCorp) worker@server:~/Fusion$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
(envFCorp) worker@server:~/Fusion$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd status
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
celeryd down: no pidfiles found
```

Please suggest how do i automate to start my celery worker and beat on start up. Please note i see error in step 3).

also tried using supervisor to automate but without luck

Thanks